# FormData() is not working in my script in certain situations

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this script that sends user input data to a ajax page. The problem I am facing is now is originally I had the script based on using the parents div to output the

ajax request which works perfectly with no errors but I realized I want to target a certain child div for the ajax request to appear at in that parent div so I made an

attempt to do so with this .parentNode.childNodes[] that always worked for me which helps me choose what child of that parent I want the ajax request to appear at but this method don't work properly with FormData() I know the problem is occurring here

```
var first_name=  elementTreeDestination.querySelector('.first_name').value;
var last_name=  elementTreeDestination.querySelector('.last_name').value;
```

So I don't know how to fix this I want to be able to choose a child div class call response-container to generate the ajax request in that parent div class call container and at the same time I want to have FormData() working correctly. So how would I solve this?

Here is my code

**index.php**

```
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

//Distinguish each execute class name
var execute = document.querySelectorAll('.execute');
 for (var i = 0; i < execute.length; i++) {
   execute[i].addEventListener('click', ajax);
 }
//

function ajax(elementTrigger){
  var element= elementTrigger.currentTarget;

  //Target the AJAX response div to also allow JS to run in that div
  var elementTreeDestination= element.parentNode.childNodes[9]; 
  /*^If I remove childNodes it works and it also works with the FormData variables below for example ... elementTreeDestination.querySelector('...') 
  but I need the ajax request to target [9] which targets the class response-container*/
 //
  var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange= function(){
      if(xhr.readyState === 4){
          elementTreeDestination.innerHTML= xhr.responseText;

 /*<Allow JS on the requested page>*/
    var exJs= elementTreeDestination.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var enableAll = exJs.length;
    for(var i=0; i < enableAll; i++){
    eval(exJs[i].text);
}
  /*</Allow JS on the requested page>*/

      }
  }

  var data= new FormData();

 var first_name=  elementTreeDestination.querySelector('.first_name').value;//Error occurs here. But if I put querySelectorAll no errors but it sends nothing
 var last_name=  elementTreeDestination.querySelector('.last_name').value; //Error occurs here. But if I put querySelectorAll no errors but it sends nothing
 /*^ I know the problem occurs due to the formData section^*/

  data.append('first_name', first_name);
data.append('last_name', last_name);

  xhr.open('POST','x');
  xhr.send(data);

}

});
</script>

<div class='container'>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <button class='execute'>Execute 1</button>
  <input class='first_name' type='text' placeholder='First Name'>
  <input class='last_name' type='text' placeholder='Last Name'>
  <div class='response-container'>
</div><!--</response-container>-->
</div><!--</container>-->

<div class='container'>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <button class='execute'>Execute 1</button>
  <input class='first_name' type='text' placeholder='First Name'>
  <input class='last_name' type='text' placeholder='Last Name'>
  <div class='response-container'>
</div><!--</response-container>-->
</div><!--</container>-->
```

**x.php**

```
<script>

alert('Welcome to page x.php');

</script>

<style>

img{
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

</style>

<img src='https://ak3.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/23831083/thumb/1.jpg'>

<h1><?php echo $_POST['first_name']; ?></h1>
<h1><?php echo $_POST['last_name']; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use

   ```
   var elementTreeDestination = element.parentNode.querySelector('.response-container');
   ```

   That way you won't have to rely on arbitrary whitespace moving the element to be `childNodes[9]`
2. the two `<input>`s aren't children of `elementTreeDestination`, so `elementTreeDestination.querySelector('.first_name').value` will likely cause a null pointer error and stop the script's execution.
   Instead, again use

   ```
   var first_name = element.parentNode.querySelector('.first_name').value;
   ```
3. It looks like you included the `ajax` function in your loop? That's not necessary or useful. Move it out of your loop.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  //Distinguish each execute class name
  var execute = document.querySelectorAll('.execute');
  for (var i = 0; i < execute.length; i++) {
    execute[i].addEventListener('click', ajax);
  }
});

function ajax(elementTrigger) {
  var element = elementTrigger.currentTarget;

  //Target the AJAX response div to also allow JS to run in that div
  var elementTreeDestination = element.parentNode.querySelector(".response-container");
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      elementTreeDestination.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

      /*<Allow JS on the requested page>*/
      var exJs = elementTreeDestination.getElementsByTagName('script');
      var enableAll = exJs.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < enableAll; i++) {
        eval(exJs[i].text);
      }
      /*</Allow JS on the requested page>*/
    }
  };


  var data = new FormData();

  var first_name = element.parentNode.querySelector('.first_name').value;
  var last_name = element.parentNode.querySelector('.last_name').value;

  data.append('first_name', first_name);
  data.append('last_name', last_name);

  console.log(first_name, last_name);

  xhr.open('POST', 'x');
  xhr.send(data);

}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <button class='execute'>Execute 1</button>
  <input class='first_name' type='text' placeholder='First Name' value='Alice'>
  <input class='last_name' type='text' placeholder='Last Name' value='Allison'>
  <div class='response-container'>
  </div>
  <!--</response-container>-->
</div>
<!--</container>-->

<div class='container'>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <button class='execute'>Execute 1</button>
  <input class='first_name' type='text' placeholder='First Name'>
  <input class='last_name' type='text' placeholder='Last Name'>
  <div class='response-container'>
  </div>
  <!--</response-container>-->
</div>
<!--</container>-->
```

Comment: Final note: you might want to look into jQuery and `fetch()`.